# SgmlLinkExtractor() does not extract all the URLs

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

Hy all,

I have a strange problem.

It seems like Scrapy is not extracting all the existing URLs from a page. I.e it finds/extracts URLs found on this type of tag(s):

```
<a href="https://www.mysite.com/members/foreign-members" class="..." title="">

            Foreign members
</a>
```

but it does not find/extract the URLs on this type of tag(s):

```
<a class="..." style="..." href="https://www.mysite.com/members/members/8199" title="...">
    ...
    <span title="...">...</span>
</a>
```

What can be the problem?
Because the href attribute it is not the first one? I noticed that It does not find URLs when href it is not the first attribute. Like you see, I don't have any regex that define what URLs to extract so It should extract all of them.

Here is a sample of my Spider code:

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'S'                                        
    start_urls = ['https://www.mysite.com/members/members/']

    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(), callback = 'parse_members'),           
    )
    ...
```

Do anyone has s solution?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Without a sample page it's quite difficult to investigate. Have you checked using `scrapy shell <sample_url>` and calling `SgmlLinkExtractor().extract_links(response)`?

Comment: You can try an alternative link extractor like `LxmlParserLinkExtractor` (`from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.lxmlhtml import LxmlParserLinkExtractor`)

Comment: Hy Paul, this is the start url: https://www.knaw.nl/en/members/members#b_start=0. 

As you imagine, I want to extract the URLs towards the members and also the URLs towards the next page(s)

I tried both suggestions what you wrote above but no succes.

Comment: It looks to me that the members are loaded through some Javascript (I can see an XHR request to `https://www.knaw.nl/en/members/members/@@faceted_query?b_start%5B%5D=0...`). You'll need to emulate that I think (or is there a link in the page for non-Javascript enabled visitors?)

Comment: Tx for the answer.
But I realy don't know how to fix it and I don't understand your answer. I am a beginner in web dev. So it will be much apreciated if you give me more clues :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used firebug to look at the link you shared, opened 'net' section and realized that this is the link you are after:

```
$ scrapy shell "https://www.knaw.nl/en/members/members/@@faceted_query?b_start[]=0&version=cb403bd0d9fed8ab5ee81b142c8d1f9a"
...
>>> sel.xpath('//a/@href').extract()
[u'https://www.knaw.nl/en/members/members/8199', 
 u'https://www.knaw.nl/en/members/members/8199', 
 u'https://www.knaw.nl/en/members/members/3786', 
 u'https://www.knaw.nl/en/members/members/3786',
 ...]
```

this can be used in a spider like:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import Selector

class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    ...
    start_urls = ['https://www.knaw.nl/en/members/members/@@faceted_query?b_start[]=0&version=cb403bd0d9fed8ab5ee81b142c8d1f9a']

    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        for link in sel.xpath('').extract():
            yield Request(url=link, callback=self.some_function_to _extract_page)
```

with this url you can also use CrawlSpider with SgmlLinkExtractor:

```
>>> from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
>>> SgmlLinkExtractor().extract_links(response)
[Link(url='https://www.knaw.nl/en/members/members/8199', .....]
```

as a side note, notice that the links appear the same twice, you may try to extract them once of let scrapy filter them for you, its done automatically, so in its default, scrapy will not scrape them twice.